# Teletalk huawei 3G Modem Install Error Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Tags: networking, usb-modem, modem, 3g

I am a new user on Ubuntu. Now 30 days ago I installed Ubuntu 18.04 LTS Version in My PC. But Many time I try to Teletalk Modem & I face much error. I was find help in Ubuntu forums but I could not found any help.Now I need your help. Please help me how to install Teletalk Modem in Ubuntu 18.04 LTS. Please help me.....!

[Teletalk Modem Software Link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=12XnxLw0QCea_NWIi-XpQy0rYjLEkr_6-)

Comment: You need to provide much more detailed information. What have you tried? What was the actual result? What was the expected result?

Comment: I will provide much more detailed information as soon as possible.